# Swedish letters missing in google-vision Api response

Tags: android, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to use Google Cloud Vision with TEXT_DETECTION to perform OCR. It works perfect and i get the response in a Json object. The problem is that when I try to detect swedish text it does not return swedish letters. Api correctly detects the local. it returns the response but does not include swedish letters like (ä,ö) etc.

I have tried to set local in the request but it does not work.

I just want to get swedish letters in response. I have no idea what should i do?

if someone give some link to google-vision discussion thread what will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Swedish is your only language, may be try to use LanguageHints.
https://cloud.google.com/vision/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#imagecontext

Out of blue, Swedish works well for you (Percentage of success)?

Thanks!
~Suman

Comment: sumandas: language is correctly detected and text ocr is perfect. but in response it does not include swedish letters.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by text ocr is perfect if letters are not included?

Comment: By adding language hint it only extracts that particular language from image. But fortunately it includes Swedish characters in response. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

The response doesn't respond with the Swedish characters åäö. It only responds with ao instead of åäö. Really irritating.

Comment: Use Language Hint. It will return proper swedish letters in  response.